# Parse-server sharp package in beforeSaveFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, parse-server, sharp

I want to use this package: [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) in beforeSaveFile trigger but it doesn't work. beforeSaveFile doesn't change anything.

My codes:

```js
    Parse.Cloud.define('test', async (req) => {
      try {
        const Resim = Parse.Object.extend('Resim')
        const obj = new Resim()
        const { photo } = req.params
    
        let uploadedFile = await new Parse.File(
          'galleryFile',
          { base64: photo },
          'image/png'
        )
        obj.set('photo', uploadedFile)
        const data = await obj.save()
        return data
      } catch (error) {
        throw error
      }
    })
    
    Parse.Cloud.beforeSaveFile(async (req) => {
      const image = await sharp(req.file).resize(256)
      return image
    })
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: `sharp()` function expects a filename or a Buffer as first parameter, you are passing in `req.file` which is an instance of `Parse.File` which is an Object with some props and methods.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. This is the solution:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSaveFile(async (req) => {
    const file = req.file
    const fileData = await file.getData()
    const str = fileData.toString('base64')
    const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(str, 'base64')
  
    const newImageBuffer = await sharp(imageBuffer)
      .resize(800, 800)
      .webp({ quality: 70, lossless: true })
      .toBuffer()
  
    return new Parse.File(
      'image',
      { base64: newImageBuffer.toString('base64') },
      'image/webp'
    )
  })
```